# Proof of the first Sylow theorem in the Artin's textbook

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $|G|=p^n m$. Artin is using the following nice trick to show existence of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Let $S$ be the set of all subsets of $G$ of cardinality $p^n$. Then, $G$ acts on $S$ and $|S|= \binom{p^n m}{p^n}$ is not divisible by $p$. Then there is an orbit of order not divisible by $p$, say orbit $GU$. So
$$
|Stab(U)| |GU|=|G|=p^n m.
$$
Then he claims $|Stab(U)|=p^n$ and so $Stab(U)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

I don't understand why we could not have $m=m_1 m_2$, $m_1 >1$ and $m_2 >1$ and $|Stab(U)|=p^n m_1$?

Comment: Argue that $U = Stab(U) U$; hence, $U$ is a disjoint union of $Stab(U)$-cosets (left or right, I never remember). Thus, $\left|Stab\left(U\right)\right| \mid \left|U\right| = p^n$. Hence, $\left|Stab\left(U\right)\right|$ is a power of $p$.

Comment: What Artin textbook are you talking about? Because Mike Artin's *Algebra* seems to do it right. But there is more than one Artin, and each one probably has more than one book....

Comment: I think we talking about the same textbook: M. Artin, Algebra.

Comment: Weird. Isn't my argument part of Lemma 7.7.9?

Comment: Nope. There is no lemma 7.7.9 in my version. That is because I have 1st edition, and you probably have 2nd edition, where this argument was added.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that's likely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving Sylow's first theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472885/proving-sylows-first-theorem)

Comment: The question was about particular argument in one textbook, whether it is complete or not. Discussion in the comments answered my question 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $p^n \nmid |GU| \Rightarrow p^n \mid |\operatorname{Stab}(U)| \Rightarrow |\operatorname{Stab}(U)| \ge p^n$, as you have correctly pointed out. But consider that $\operatorname{Stab}(U)=\{g \in G\mid gU=U\}$, so that, given $a \in U$, $\forall g \in \operatorname{Stab}(U)$ it is $ga \in U$; thence, there's a map $\psi_a\colon \operatorname{Stab}(U)  \rightarrow U$, $g \mapsto ga$, injective by right cancellation, which yields $|\operatorname{Stab}(U)|\le |U|=p^n$. Finally, we are just left with $|\operatorname{Stab}(U)|=p^n$.