# Statement of Sylow's first theorem

Tags: group-theory

I've been taught that the first Sylow theorem states:

> If $|G|=n$ and $p^km=n$ for $p$ prime and $p\not\mid m$, then $|G|$ has a subgroup of order $p^k$.

However, this website states the theorem differently:

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-sylow-theorems

> Let $G$ be a finite group. If $p$ is a prime, $k\geq0$, and $p^k$ is a divisor of $|G|$ then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^k$.

From this definition, it sounds like *any* prime power that divides $|G|$ has a subgroup of that order, which is different statement than the one my textbook gives. I've read through the proof on the Math Online and couldn't see anything wrong about it, yet I still have doubts... Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** So both statements are true, and I see now that the MathOnline one is stronger. But when I look up "Sylow's First Theorem" on the Internet I tend to find proofs of the weaker statement. I wonder why it's the weaker statement that gets presented everywhere?

Comment: They are both true statements, so in that sense they are equivalent, though one is clearly a stronger statement than the other. However, getting from the weaker statement to the stronger is a lot easier than proving the weaker statement itself.

Comment: Thank you. Are both called Sylow's First Theorem, or does one of them go by a different name? For some reason I feel like stronger statement was just as straightforward to prove, so I wonder why I wasn't presented that one in class.

Comment: Various sources will call either Sylow's First Theorem. Whether they should is another question (which would require reading the original paper by Sylow to figure out and I have never read that).

Comment: In the first statement, do you mean $p^k m = n$ instead of $p^k m \mid n$ ?

Comment: Yes, thank you for catching my mistake. It's fixed now.

Comment: By the way, the following is also true: every subgroup of cardinal $p^d$ appears in a chain of subgroups $\{e\} ⊆ H_1 ⊆H_2 ⊆ ⋯ ⊆ H_k ⊆ G$ where $|H_i| = p^i$ and $k$ is maximal such that $p^k \mid n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472885/proving-sylows-first-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathonline version is strictly stronger than the first one, so these statements are not equivalent. However, these two statements are both right.

Comment: Is it in fact stronger in any formal sense?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Probably not, but it is stronger in standard mathematical usage. ("A proved this result and then 10 years later B proved this stronger result ...")